# Conditional counting and summation in SQL

Tags: aggregate, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have this raw table below. What I would like to do is conditionally count the number of reviews based upon the 3 'hit types'.

```
Reviewer date   id  3_hit   2_hit   1_hit
jack    1 Sep   1   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
jack    1 Sep   1   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
jack    1 Sep   3   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
jack    1 Sep   4   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
jack    1 Sep   5   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
tim     2 Sep   6   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
tim     2 Sep   7   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE
```

There are 3 conditions I would like to query on:

1. If an id is TRUE for 3_hit AND also has TRUE for either 2_hit or 1_hit in another row, then count as 1 "3_hit".
2. If an id is TRUE for 2_hit, but also as TRUE for 1_hit in another row, then count as 1 "2_hit".
3. If an id is TRUE for 1_hit, and FALSE for 2_hit and 3_hit, then count as 1 "1_hit".

*note, pretend the 1st table has the timestamp in the date field (not just the date)

```
Reviewer date   type    r_count    max time min time    time_h
jack    1 Sep   3_hit          2    7:00 PM    1:00 PM  6
jack    1 Sep   2_hit          2    5:00 PM    1:00 PM  4
tim     2 Sep   3_hit          1    5:00 PM    1:00 PM  4
tim     2 Sep   1_hit          1    3:00 PM    1:00 PM  2
```

I would then like to be able to get the time per review for each type, it would look as follows:

```
reviewer    date    review type r_count reviews/hour
jack       1 Sep       3_hit       2    2/6
jack       1 Sep       2_hit       2    2/4
tim        2 Sep       3_hit       1    2/4
tim        2 Sep       1_hit       1    1/2
```

I know this will require a few levels of aggregation, which is fine. The most important thing is that the last table is filterable using Looker, so that I can filter by review type and date.

I'm not sure this is possible in SQL, but I can't figure out how to simulate a new column and then count based on how many results are in that column. Is this possible? I guess it would be a pivot of sorts.

**Note** I also realize that the reviews per hour won't exactly be accurate, as there will be overlap in time taken to review different reviews. Unfortunately, this date/time is the best I have to do this kind of analysis.

Would appreciate any and all help on this! Thanks!

Comment: MySQL or Snowflake? Please tag only one database.

Comment: Sorry, removed MySQL and left Snowflake.

Comment: When you say "also has TRUE for either 2_hit or 1_hit in another row" do you mean any other row in the dataset, any other row with the same reviewer/date, any other row with the same reviewer/date/id - or something else?

It would also be easier to provide an accurate solution (that matched your outputs) if you could provide a sample dataset that was complete i.e. included the time portion of the dates